# MotionLayout how rotate element?

Tags: kotlin, android-motionlayout

Now I have a motion with two elements. When first is 50% duration then second starts. But I want to rotate second element in half transition to the end. I tryed to do this in KeyCycle but it Doesnt work. Maybe I need to do this in KeyAttribute? But it doesn't work too. Maybe someone give me a tip?

Scene:

```
<Transition
    motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="1500">

    <KeyFrameSet>

        <KeyPosition
            motion:framePosition="50"
            motion:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/imageView"
            motion:percentX="1" />

        <KeyPosition
            motion:framePosition="50"
            motion:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/cardYes"
            motion:percentX="0" />

        <KeyCycle
            android:translationY="50dp"
            motion:framePosition="300"
            motion:motionTarget="@+id/imageView"
            motion:waveOffset="50dp"
            motion:wavePeriod="2"
            motion:waveShape="sin" />
    </KeyFrameSet>

</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/cardYes"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/cardYes"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
</ConstraintSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

must have 3 KeyCycle can work well.

In your case, maybe you need code like this:

```
 <KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyAttribute
            android:rotation="0"
            motion:framePosition="50"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/view"
            />
        <KeyAttribute
            android:rotation="360"
            motion:framePosition="100"
            motion:motionTarget="@id/view"
            />
</KeyFrameSet>
```